# Text inserted into Hyperlink field shows up but does not act as a link

Tags: python-2.7, ms-access, hyperlink, ms-access-2003, pyodbc

I'm having difficulty getting my pyodbc inserted hyperlinks to work in my Access 2003 database.  It appears to look like a hyperlink but does nothing when clicked on. For it to work,  I have to edit it in Access and only then does it recognize that, "oh yeah that is a hyperlink".

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ= C:\\Users\\multidata\\Documents\\db1.mdb;")

cur = cnxn.cursor()
#hyperlink is the text file. table1 is hyperlink column in ms access
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(table1, table2) values ('C:\\Users\\multidata\\Desktop\\MC1\\7-31-14_711_EX_2153.txt ', 'y')")
cnxn.commit()
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: As this stands, I don't really see what your asking... as such, it's likely to be closed.

Comment: I'm asking if there is something I can put in the python code so access 2003 can recognize that it is a hyperlink.

Comment: Why not store links as text? Then in form interface, have textbox controls serve as hyperlinks. Otherwise, there is no such hyperlink data type in Jet/ACE SQL engine. You would need to run VBA, specifically the DAO field property. See this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133523/what-is-the-ms-access-sql-syntax-to-create-a-field-of-type-hyperlink). I don't know if there is a Python library for Access VBA DAO object.

Comment: @Parfait *"there is no such hyperlink data type in Jet/ACE SQL engine"* - What's [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b87X6.png) then?

Comment: Gord, hyperlink is not a [Jet SQL data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms713678%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Possibly, it is an Access UI feature interacting with a text field. Hence this query will never work as a stored query or VBA query: `ALTER Table1 ADD COLUMN docLink Hyperlink;` You will receive 'Syntax error in data definition'.

Comment: @Parfait Yes, an Access "Hyperlink" field is really a subtype of the Jet/ACE "Memo" (or "Long Text") field, but that does not preclude us from manipulating their contents via ODBC. We can successfully use DML statements with Hyperlink fields if we format them correctly (as per my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Hyperlink field in Access is a text field containing a number of "parts" separated by hash marks (`#`). Those various parts are described in the MSDN article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.hyperlinkpart).

If we want to insert a bare URL or file_path into a Hyperlink field we need to enclose it in hash marks, e.g.

```python
import pyodbc
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:\Users\Public\a2003test.mdb;'
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
hyperlink = r'C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\foo.txt'
sql = "UPDATE Table1 SET docLink=? WHERE ID=1"
crsr.execute(sql, ['#'+hyperlink+'#'])
cnxn.commit()
crsr.close()
cnxn.close()
```